# Pusher | The file ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat.php is missing in the includes folder

Tags: php, composer-php, pusher

I am wanting to use Pusher in my application and went to download it via Composer. I successfully downloaded Composer, Paragonie, and Pusher but when I included

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

at the top of my PHP file and go to my website I run into the error

```
The file ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat.php is missing in the includes folder.
```

I have paragonie installed with sodium_compat as a subfolder as well. It downloaded automatically with the Pusher install. I am running PHP version 7.2.